# Click anywhere to focus in CKEditor

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer-6, focus, ckeditor

In FireFox, I can click anywhere in CKEditor (350px x 250px) to place focus on a single paragraph of text located at the top of the editor.  However, in IE6 (I know, but our client insists) I must click directly atop the paragraph to focus the cursor and subsequently edit the text.

CKEditor creates the following:

```
<iframe>
<html>
   <head>...</head>
   <body spellcheck="true">
      <p>some text to edit</p>
   </body>
</html>
</iframe>
```

I suspect this is an IE6 problem; any ideas???

**EDIT:**
[Apparently a known problem.](http://dev.fckeditor.net/ticket/1659)

Comment: Doesn't the ticket say fixed in 3.1? Are you using 3.1?

Comment: I am not using 3.1; not sure when or if the patch made the baseline.  The patch is here: http://dev.fckeditor.net/attachment/ticket/1659/1659_9.patch

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a [known problem](http://dev.fckeditor.net/ticket/1659) apparently fixed in v3.1.

Answer (score 2):

I just had the same problem with the 4.2.2 release and IE 8 and was able to fix it with this code in the `instanceReady` event. It sets the focus when the user clicks anywhere in the CKEditor edit region.

```
CKEDITOR.on( 'instanceReady', function( ev ) {
    $('iframe.cke_wysiwyg_frame', ev.editor.container.$).contents().on('click', function() {
        ev.editor.focus();
    });
});
```

Comment: I had this same problem with 4.3 release and IE 8.  Your solution worked perfectly for me.  The only thing I did was throw it in some <!--[if lte IE 8]>  tags so it would only be used for IE8 and below.

Answer (score 1):

As the ticket date shows, the bug is still present, it hasn't been fixed in the 3.1 release.

Comment: I cut-and-pasted code from the 3.1 release into our version (3.0.1) and corrected the problem.  Maybe the ticket has not been updated?

Comment: Sorry. I don't know what I was reading yesterday.
Obviously the ticket is fixed and you were right, I should rest a little.