# How to disable CKEditor context menu?

Tags: javascript, ckeditor

Does anybody know how to disable CKEditor's context (right click) menu?  I would expect a configuration option, but I can't find one.  I am using v3.1.  Thanks.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You need to remove the `contextmenu` plugin. See [**here**](http://cksource.com/forums/viewtopic.php?f=11&t=17216) for 3.1.

Comment: Broken in 3.1: http://dev.fckeditor.net/browser/CKEditor/trunk/_source/plugins/menu/plugin.js?rev=4971

Comment: @Upper Stage: Ah I see, crap.

Comment: @Upper Stage, thanks for makign me aware of this. I will definitely skip 3.1 now.

Comment: I would be remiss if I didn't note that 3.1 fixes some problems http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2028599/click-anywhere-to-focus-in-ckeditor

Answer (score 37):

As of version 3.6.4, the other answers in this question don't work anymore. [See bug #9284](http://dev.ckeditor.com/ticket/9284)

The three plugins that need to be disabled (using the means discussed in this question), are `contextmenu`, `liststyle` and `tabletools`. So for example, using config files:

```
CKEDITOR.editorConfig = function(config) {
    /* Your config options */
    ...
    config.removePlugins = 'contextmenu,liststyle,tabletools';
};
```

Comment: Note: you need to remove all three plugins because of their dependency http://dev.ckeditor.com/ticket/9284

Comment: This is no longer enough with 4.x, see the addClass('cke_enable_context_menu') answer

Comment: This is again enough with 4.3.2 (and potentially somewhat earlier versions).

Answer (score 9):

Ckeditor `4.7.1`

```
CKEDITOR.editorConfig = function (config) {
  config.language = 'en';
  config.toolbar = "mini";
  config.removePlugins = 'elementspath,contextmenu,liststyle,tabletools,tableselection';
  config.disableNativeSpellChecker = false;
}
```

Ckeditor `4.8.0` ('elementspath' plugin no longer need to remove)

```
CKEDITOR.editorConfig = function (config) {
  config.language = 'en';
  config.toolbar = "mini";
  config.removePlugins = 'contextmenu,liststyle,tabletools,tableselection';
  config.disableNativeSpellChecker = false;
}
```

Comment: It worked! For 4.8.0 elementspath was not needed to remove.

Answer (score 3):

There is still a practical solution, by overriding the prototype function that initializes `contextmenu` behavior:

```
CKEDITOR.dom.element.prototype.disableContextMenu = function () {
    this.on( 'contextmenu', function( event ) {
        // your contextmenu behavior
    });
};
```

NOTE: when CKEDITOR loads its JS resources dynamically you need to place it right before the `replace` call.

Comment: That worked for us. We just used an empty function for disableContextMenu though.

Answer (score 3):

You can find out which plugins require `contextmenu` in your particular build of CKEditor using the following snippet in an F12 console window in your site (assumes you have jQuery also for `$.each`):

```
$.each(CKEDITOR.plugins, function(k, v){ 
    v.requires && console.log("Plugin '" + k + "' requires: " + v.requires) 
})
```

For example:

> Plugin 'tabletools' requires table,dialog,contextmenu

Which you can then use to help you with your `config.removePlugins` - in my case:

```
config.removePlugins = 'tabletools,contextmenu'
```

Comment: DIY are always the best kind of answers! Cheers

Answer (score 2):

I needed to disable all of the following to get this to work.

```
config.removePlugins = 'language,tableresize,liststyle,tabletools,scayt,menubutton,contextmenu';
```

Previously we did not need language or tableresize - but a newer version of ckeditor seems to require that.

I discovered this in looking at the output in F12 dev tools on chrome.

Answer (score 2):

Hold down the ctrl button while right clicking to by-pass the context menu and access spell checker etc.

Comment: Thank you! I was trying to access the browser Inspector (didn't want to change config settings). The part of the toolbar I was trying to inspect was in the contents of a "dropdown" on the toolbar, and while Ctrl + right click didn't work for that, this gave me the idea to try Shift + right click, which did work.

Answer (score 1):

For version 4.2, I put the following at the end of my config.js file

```
CKEDITOR.on('instanceReady', function(ev) {
   ev.editor.editable().addClass('cke_enable_context_menu')
});
```

Comment: Thanks, this seems to be the only way since their buggs persist

Answer (score 0):

With CKEditor 3.6 I was able to disable context menu by removing the contextmenu plugin as suggested above.
To do this, you have to configure the editor with the removePlugins option.
For instance:

```
CKEDITOR.replace('my_editor', {
    removePlugins : 'contextmenu'
});
```

It can also be disabled globally from the config.js file:

```
CKEDITOR.editorConfig = function(config) {
    /* Your config options */
    ...
    config.removePlugins = 'contextmenu';
};
```

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately since CKEditor 3.6/4.0 this does not work anymore.

See bug report: http://dev.ckeditor.com/ticket/9284

Comment: Isn't this what Xeon06 said and he provided also the new configuration?

Comment: yes, I read and tried that, does not work for me either (with latest stable 3.6.4).

Comment: As I am catching the paste event: ev.editor.on('paste', function(evt) { ... } I thought this would interfere with the provided solution. However, after removing this, I still get the context menu of ckeditor. This is [my current config.js](http://pastebin.com/nhYafV9i)

Answer (score 0):

In CKEditor 4.x, (I tested 4.2.2) you must do both:

`CKEDITOR.replace('my_editor', {
    removePlugins : 'contextmenu'
});`

And

```
CKEDITOR.editorConfig = function(config) {
/* Your config options */
...
config.removePlugins = ''liststyle,tabletools,contextmenu'';
};
```

All three of those will automatically require contextmenu if you don't disable them.

Comment: Actually, you don't have to do both. In the inline configuration you disabled just one plugin (contextmenu) that's why it did not work. `CKEDITOR.replace('my_editor', { removePlugins : 'liststyle,tabletools,contextmenu' });` will do the trick

Answer (score 0):

It's possible to completely disable the context menu adding this line to your config file (tipically fckconfig.js):

```
FCKConfig.ContextMenu = [];
```