# How to configure simple links and image attaching in ckeditor?

Tags: django, image, hyperlink, ckeditor

I'm using django-ckeditor and I have some problems with the links and images.

**Regarding Links:**

[image: Add link interface]

In this interface you can see that this is not usable by the end users, as it is too complex and can lead to errors and security issues, as the button `Browse Server` literally permits the user browse uploaded content. What I want is something really simple: just an input text that automatically appends http (if not typed by user) and that opens the link in a new window aka target `_blank`.

I've tried to do so editing config.js with the following code. This has removed the `Upload` and `Advanced` tabs, removed unnecessary widgets from `Info` tab and made target `_blank` by default. But the `Target` tab is still present and the users can change it, as I apparently can't remove this tab, or else the default target is ignored I'm stuck with this. So, **how can I set the target to `_blank` and remove the `Target` tab too?** Is there a way to hide this tab, but not remove it?

```
CKEDITOR.on('dialogDefinition', function(ev) {
    // Take the dialog name and its definition from the event data.
    var dialogName = ev.data.name;
    var dialogDefinition = ev.data.definition;

    // Check if the definition is from the dialog we're
    // interested in (the 'link' dialog).
    if (dialogName == 'link') {
        // Remove the 'Target', 'Upload' and 'Advanced' tabs from the 'Link' dialog.
//        dialogDefinition.removeContents('target');
        dialogDefinition.removeContents('upload');
        dialogDefinition.removeContents('advanced');

        // Get a reference to the 'Link Info' tab.
        var infoTab = dialogDefinition.getContents('info');

        // Remove unnecessary widgets from the 'Link Info' tab.         
        infoTab.remove('linkType');
        infoTab.remove('protocol');
        infoTab.remove('browse');

        // Get a reference to the "Target" tab.
        var targetTab = dialogDefinition.getContents('target');
        // Set the default value for the URL field.
        var targetField = targetTab.get('linkTargetType');
        targetField['default'] = '_blank';
    }

});
```

**Regarding images:**

There is a very similar situation: several tabs with too much options. What I need is something as easy as the option to attach images in Stackoverflow. **Is there any free plugin that could allow me to add images through a link and by uploading them from the computer (with previsualization) using the ckeditor?**

Thanks!

Answer (score 21, accepted):

Finally I get simple dialogs for: including links, attaching images from a link or uploading from the computer and to include Youtube videos in a simple way. To do this I've edited the configuration file called `config.js` and it looks like this for my version CKeditor 4.1.2:

```
CKEDITOR.editorConfig = function( config ) {
    // Define changes to default configuration here.
    // For the complete reference:
    // http://docs.ckeditor.com/#!/api/CKEDITOR.config

    // Comment the following line in DEBUG mode:
    config.removePlugins = 'devtools';

    // See the most common block elements.
    config.format_tags = 'p;h1;h2;h3;pre';

    // Make dialogs simpler.
    config.removeDialogTabs = 'image:advanced;image:Link;link:advanced;link:upload';
    config.linkShowTargetTab = false;

    // In CKEditor 4.1 or higher you need to disable ACF (Advanced Content Filter)
    // to make Youtube plugin work:
    config.allowedContent = true;
};

CKEDITOR.on('dialogDefinition', function(ev) {
    // Take the dialog name and its definition from the event data.
    var dialogName = ev.data.name;
    var dialogDefinition = ev.data.definition;

    // Check if the definition is from the dialog we're
    // interested in (the 'link' dialog).
    if (dialogName == 'link') {
//        Remove the 'Upload' and 'Advanced' tabs from the 'Link' dialog.
//        dialogDefinition.removeContents('upload');
//        dialogDefinition.removeContents('advanced');

        // Get a reference to the 'Link Info' tab.
        var infoTab = dialogDefinition.getContents('info');
        // Remove unnecessary widgets from the 'Link Info' tab.
        infoTab.remove('linkType');
        infoTab.remove('protocol');
        infoTab.remove('browse');

        // Get a reference to the "Target" tab and set default to '_blank'
        var targetTab = dialogDefinition.getContents('target');
        var targetField = targetTab.get('linkTargetType');
        targetField['default'] = '_blank';

    } else if (dialogName == 'image') {
//        Remove the 'Link' and 'Advanced' tabs from the 'Image' dialog.
//        dialogDefinition.removeContents('Link');
//        dialogDefinition.removeContents('advanced');

        // Get a reference to the 'Image Info' tab.
        var infoTab = dialogDefinition.getContents('info');
        // Remove unnecessary widgets/elements from the 'Image Info' tab.
        infoTab.remove('browse');
        infoTab.remove('txtHSpace');
        infoTab.remove('txtVSpace');
        infoTab.remove('txtBorder');
        // infoTab.remove('cmbAlign');

    }
});
```

To do this I've read a lot of documentation, but the best pages that have inpired me are the following:

- http://ckeditor.com/ckeditor_4.1rc/samples/plugins/toolbar/toolbar.html
- http://ckeditor.com/forums/Support/Removing-Tabs-Image-Dialog
- http://ckeditor.com/forums/CKEditor/Complete-list-of-toolbar-items
- http://khaledben.wordpress.com/2012/04/28/customize-ckeditor-dialog/
- http://www.question2answer.org/qa/13255/simple-ckeditor-how-to-modify-it-to-be-simple-solution

I hope this helps someone else with the same problem. Cheers!

Comment: Using the latest version `4.4.3` when removing e.g. `protocol` from link it goes bananas for me. Errors. Easiest solution was to do `config.removePlugins='link'` and then just build a simple link plugin of my own. Really crappy plugin shipped by CKEditor. At least give us a simple mode for it. One that doesn't try to be so "clever".

Comment: Wrote some words about it here: http://danielwertheim.se/2014/08/15/ckeditor-the-link-plugin-is-painfully-clever/

Answer (score 6):

Here are a lot of tweaks I did for CKEditor v3.6.1 to make it usable (esp. image dialog and link dialog). They seem to work for CKEditor 4.x as well, just take what you need for your `config.js`:

```
CKEDITOR.editorConfig = function( config ) {
    // Define changes to default configuration here. For example:
    config.language = 'de';
    config.extraPlugins = 'colordialog';
    // config.extraPlugins = 'matheeditor';
    // config.uiColor = '#AADC6E';
    // config.image_previewText = CKEDITOR.tools.repeat('Custom lorem ipsum text here', 8 );
    // config.contentsLanguage = 'de';

    config.linkShowAdvancedTab = false;
    config.linkShowTargetTab = false; 

    config.height = 350;
    config.width = 680;

    // change color palette
    config.colorButton_colors = 'F00,11C11D,00F,B700B7,FF8C00,008080,808080,D3D3D3';
    config.colorButton_enableMore = false;

    // smaller editor-width for mobile devices
    if (/iPhone|iPod/i.test(navigator.userAgent)) {
        config.width = 300;
    }

    // for resizing the editor window
    config.resize_minHeight = 350;
    config.resize_maxHeight = 880;
    config.resize_maxWidth = 910;

    // remove all formatting from pasted text
    config.forcePasteAsPlainText = true;

    // remove font size, family, bg color from pasted text
    config.pasteFromWordRemoveFontStyles = true;

    // allow browser's spell checker
    config.disableNativeSpellChecker = false;

    // disable ckeditor context menu to allow native context menu (works on holding CTRL)
    // open: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2246631/how-to-disable-ckeditor-context-menu/12477378

    // shortcuts for firefox and chrome (editor breaks if assigned in IE9)
    // if(navigator.userAgent.toLowerCase().indexOf('firefox') > -1 || navigator.userAgent.toLowerCase().indexOf('chrome') > -1) {
    if ( !(/MSIE (\d+\.\d+);/.test(navigator.userAgent)) ) {
        config.keystrokes = [
            // [ CKEDITOR.SHIFT + 45, 'pastefromword' ], //INS
            [ CKEDITOR.CTRL + 76, 'link' ], //L
            [ CKEDITOR.CTRL + CKEDITOR.ALT + 66, 'image' ], //B
            [ CKEDITOR.CTRL + CKEDITOR.SHIFT + 77, 'specialchar' ], //M
            [ CKEDITOR.CTRL + CKEDITOR.SHIFT + 188, 'subscript' ], //COMMA
            [ CKEDITOR.CTRL + CKEDITOR.SHIFT + 109, 'subscript' ], //-
            [ CKEDITOR.CTRL + CKEDITOR.SHIFT + 191, 'subscript' ], //#
            [ CKEDITOR.CTRL + CKEDITOR.SHIFT + 190, 'superscript' ], //PERIOD
            [ CKEDITOR.CTRL + CKEDITOR.SHIFT + 107, 'superscript' ], //+
            [ CKEDITOR.CTRL + 66, 'bold' ], //B
            [ CKEDITOR.CTRL + 73, 'italic' ], //I
            [ CKEDITOR.CTRL + 85, 'underline' ], //U
            [ CKEDITOR.CTRL + CKEDITOR.SHIFT + 70, 'bold' ], //F
            [ CKEDITOR.CTRL + CKEDITOR.SHIFT + 75, 'italic' ], //K
            [ CKEDITOR.CTRL + CKEDITOR.SHIFT + 85, 'underline' ], //U
        ];
    }
};

CKEDITOR.on( 'dialogDefinition', function( ev ) {
    // take the dialog name and its definition from the event data
    var dialogName = ev.data.name;
    var dialogDefinition = ev.data.definition;
    //var dialog = CKEDITOR.dialog.getCurrent(); 
    //alert( dialog.getName() );

    // check if the definition is from the dialog we are interested in (the 'link' dialog).
    if(dialogName == 'link') {

        dialogDefinition.onShow = function () {
            var dialog = CKEDITOR.dialog.getCurrent(); 
            //dialog.hidePage( 'target' ); // via config 
            //dialog.hidePage( 'advanced' ); // via config 
            elem = dialog.getContentElement('info','anchorOptions');    
            elem.getElement().hide();
            elem = dialog.getContentElement('info','emailOptions'); 
            elem.getElement().hide();
            var elem = dialog.getContentElement('info','linkType'); 
            elem.getElement().hide();
            elem = dialog.getContentElement('info','protocol'); 
            elem.disable();
        };

    }
    else if(dialogName == 'image') {

        // get a reference to the 'Link Info' tab.
        var infoTab = dialogDefinition.getContents('info');
        // remove unnecessary fields
        infoTab.remove('ratioLock');
        infoTab.remove('txtHeight');         
        infoTab.remove('txtWidth');         
        infoTab.remove('txtBorder');
        infoTab.remove('txtHSpace');
        infoTab.remove('txtVSpace');
        infoTab.remove('cmbAlign');

        //hide image preview (v2)
        //field = infoTab.get( 'htmlPreview' );
        //field.style = 'display:none';

        // memo: dialogDefinition.onShow = ... throws JS error (C.preview not defined) 
        dialogDefinition.onLoad = function () {
            var dialog = CKEDITOR.dialog.getCurrent(); 

            // hide image preview
            var elem = dialog.getContentElement('info','htmlPreview');  
            elem.getElement().hide();

            // hide tabs and show only upload
            dialog.hidePage('Link'); 
            dialog.hidePage('advanced'); 
            this.selectPage('Upload');

            // hide url on start up, prevent user input external image URLs 
            // goes in onShow of image.js: dialog.hidePage('info'); 

            // hide ok button so that upload button can only be used
            // goes in onShow of image.js: document.getElementById(this.getButton('ok').domId).style.display='none';

            // on tab switching or automatic after upload
            this.on('selectPage', function (e) {
                // show okay button of ckeditor dialog
                document.getElementById(this.getButton('ok').domId).style.display='inline';
                // after upload the selectPage is fired, show Bild-Info then
                dialog.showPage( 'info' ); 
            });
        };

    }
    else if(dialogName == 'table') {
        dialogDefinition.removeContents('advanced');
    }

});
```

Answer (score 6):

If you are using django-ckeditor, you can simply have the following configuration in the settings.py file. You can configure it to your needs. No need to mess with JS.

```
CKEDITOR_CONFIGS = {
    'default': {
        'toolbar': 'Custom',
        'toolbar_Custom': [
            ['Bold', 'Italic', 'Underline', 'Strike'],
            [
                'NumberedList',
                'BulletedList',
                'Outdent',
                'Indent',
                '-',
                'JustifyLeft',
                'JustifyCenter',
                'JustifyRight',
                'JustifyBlock'
            ],
            ['Link', 'Unlink'],
            ['RemoveFormat', 'Source'],
        ],
        'height': 300,
        'width': 695,
        'linkShowAdvancedTab': False,
        'linkShowTargetTab': True,
    },
}
```

Comment: Thanks for this answer. I'll add another item:  'removeDialogTabs': 'link:upload',

Answer (score 3):

### Regarding links

Feel free to remove "Target" tab:

```
dialogDefinition.removeContents( 'target' );
```

Use the power of `dataProcessor` instead:

```
CKEDITOR.replace( 'editor1', {
    on: {
        instanceReady: function() {
            this.dataProcessor.htmlFilter.addRules( {
                elements: {
                    a: function( element ) {
                        element.attributes.target = '_blank';
                    }
                }
            });
        }
    }
} );
```

This will add `target="_blank"` to all `<a>` elements in editor output. See [docs](http://docs.cksource.com/CKEditor_3.x/Developers_Guide/Data_Processor) to know more.

### Regarding images

There's nothing much beyond CKFinder (commercial), KCFinder, PDW File Browser and Jasfinder. At least I cannot recall any more.

Comment: Thanks @oleq for your answer, but finally I've solved it in a different way. You can have a look at my answer, but thanks anyway! :)