# CKEDITOR 4 Inline mode Toolbar in LI contenteditable

Tags: ckeditor, inline, toolbar, bulletedlist

In CKEDITOR 4 I'm using the inline mode

I have a BulletedList with `<ul contenteditable="true">`

and when I press ENTER I can't not create a new LI with a `<P contentenditable="true">` children to have the toolbar for format text options.

[Here the JSFIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/9vxKW/6/)

[And here the list plugin source](https://github.com/ckeditor/ckeditor-dev/blob/master/plugins/list/plugin.js)

Answer (score 0):

You cannot build your editor on `<ul>` element because CKEditor wasn't designed to work like that. You can find the list of editable elements by calling `CKEDITOR.dtd.$editable` in your console:

```
CKEDITOR.dtd.$editable
>>> Object {address: 1, article: 1, aside: 1, blockquote: 1, body: 1…}
```

You can wrap your list in div element, make it editable and strip out when retrieving data. [There's a simple example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17030689/how-to-configure-simple-links-and-image-attaching-in-ckeditor/17039238#17039238) of how to modify elements on editor output. You'll need to `return false` when your div is processed. This is it.

You can also do this with `RegExp` but I don't find it gentle ;)