# Cannot disable right click menu in CKEditor 4.4.2

Tags: javascript, ckeditor

I want to disable the right click on CKEditor version 4.4.2. I create my editor in a JSP like this:

```
<div class="wideText_areaWrapper">
    <span style="float: none;">Case Summary</span>
    <textarea id="chiefComplaint" name="input_long" class="input_textarea1"></textarea>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        CKEDITOR.replace('chiefComplaint', {}); 
    </script> 
</div>
```

I found the following solution, but the menu still works fine!

```
config.removePlugins = menu,menubutton,toolbar,contextmenu';
```

How can I disable it if this does not work?

Comment: What does "still active" mean? Do you mean you don't want to see the contectmenu event? Or do you still see the menu? How did you try to disable it?

Comment: Did you see this question: http://stackoverflow.com/q/2246631/694325 ? If that did not satisfy your needs, describe the problem that you face and what you did to try and fix it. If it helps, close this question :)

Comment: i seen that question but i am not getting what exactly

Comment: i seen that question but it won't help i just want to disable right click on ckeditor ...

Comment: That question specifically asks how to disable the right click menu. How is that different from this? The answers look like they are nicely versioned as well.

Comment: But sir in my case that is not working.......

Comment: Yes, but How is it not working? Do you get errors? Describe in a lot of details what happens now, what you want to happen and what method you tried (show us the configuration settings or other code you tried) :)

Comment: Sir i add ' config.removePlugins = menu,menubutton,toolbar,contextmenu';' in **config.js** of Ck editor i disable right click functionality on the whole page but only on CK editor when i press right click it works fine

Comment: <div class="wideText_areaWrapper">
          <span style="float: none;">Case Summary</span>
          <textarea id="chiefComplaint" name="input_long"
           class="input_textarea1"></textarea>
          <script type="text/javascript">
           CKEDITOR.replace('chiefComplaint',
             {});
          </script>
         </div> above code is use in JSP page to implement CKeditor

Comment: I edited the question the reflect your info. Did you notice that there is a syntax error in `config.removePlugins = menu,menubutton,toolbar,contextmenu';`? You are missing a quote. Do you get any developer console errors?

Comment: No sir i'm not getting any error i missed that quote here only when i comment.....thank you for your time...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In version 4.15.1

```
CKEDITOR.config.enableContextMenu = false;
```

works for me.

Answer (score 0):

Add following script code into your web page.

```
function clickIE() {
    if (document.all) {
        return false;
    }
}
function clickNS(e) {
    if (document.layers || (document.getElementById && !document.all)) {
        if (e.which == 2 || e.which == 3) {
            return false;
        }
    }
}
if (document.layers) {
    document.captureEvents(Event.MOUSEDOWN);
    document.onmousedown = clickNS;
} else {
    document.onmouseup = clickNS;
    document.oncontextmenu = clickIE;
}
document.oncontextmenu = new Function("return false");
```

Comment: Its not working i add this script on document.ready my whole page not allow right click but when i click on ck editor and press right click it works....thank you for help

Answer (score 0):

Try replacing your editor like this:

```
CKEDITOR.replace( 'chiefComplaint', {
    removePlugins: "tabletools,contextmenu"
});
```

If that works, then you need to change your config to match that and the problem might be with loading the configuration file. Hopefully this is enough! If not, I'll edit or delete this answer :)

Comment: Sorry sir this code gives error on console TypeError: object is undefined

Comment: Sir i think you are not getting what exactly i want to say is it possible for you to give me your skype id..............